# (python) append used to list, then only return value if it hasn't been used

Tags: python, list

The title pretty much says it all. Following is the barebones of a small Japanese learning game that I wrote. I need to only print the kana if it has not already been printed in the current loop. Can anyone see what it is that I'm doing wrong? Thank you :)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from os     import system as cmd
from random import choice as random
from time   import sleep
from sys    import platform

m = ["ma",  "mi",  "mu",  "me",  "mo"]
y = ["ya",         "yu",         "yo"]
n = ["n"]

def get_dict(group):
    if   group == 1:
        return m
    elif group == 13:
        return y
    elif group == 14:
        return n
    elif group == 15:
        return m + y + n

def clear():
    if "win" in platform: cmd("cls")
    if "lin" in platform: cmd("clear")

def get_kana():
    global kana
    return random(kana)

## Initiate      ##
kana = get_dict(15)
speed = speed()
clear()
print disp
print "Please get ready!..."
sleep(5)

def chk_used():
    global used_kana
    numlpo = 0
    while numlpo < 50:
        numlpo = numlpo + 1
        kana = get_kana()
        if kana not in used_kana:
            used_kana = used_kana.append(kana)
            return kana
            break

def main():
    used_kana = []
    while True:
        clear()
        print disp
        print "Please write the following kana: \n"
        print "    " + chk_used()
        sleep(3)

main()
```

Comment: You should store the kana in a `dict` categorized by their starting sounds.

Comment: @Joel Cornett I was thinking of doing that, but I changed my mind because I find it a lot easier to work with lists when calling custom groups. Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Comment: You seem to be doing several things wrong, the foremost being `used_kana = used_kana.append(kana)`; that's guaranteed to set `used_kana` to `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things:

In `chk_used`, you have the line:

```
used_kana = used_kana.append(kana)
```

There's only one problem. `list.append()` returns None. Every time you do this, you're appending `kana` to `used_kana`, but then you're setting the value of `used_kana` to None.

```
used_kana.append(kana)
```

will suffice

You define `used_kana` within a function

```
def main():
    used_kana = []
```

But you try to refer to it globally. Python looks for a global variable and won't find one.

```
def chk_used():
    global used_kana
```

The solution:
pass used kana as an argument to `chk_used()`

```
def chk_used(usedCharacters):
    ...

def main():
    used_kana = []
        ...
        print "    " + chk_used(used_kana)
```

Finally:

```
    if kana not in used_kana:
        used_kana.append(kana)
        return kana
        break #there's no reason for this break. the return on the line before exits the function, your code will never ever execute this line.
```

Comment: Thank you! That was very thorough and seems to have solved every issue I was having ! I added break in afterwards as extra security, but I understand that it wouldn't necessarily do anything. Also, speed isn't defined as I stripped out 10-15 additional functions that help change the functionality of that program. Thanks heaps for your help! I now understand appending :)